# Finding the derivative of $ g(x) = tan(3x) $ using the definition

Tags: limits, derivatives

I was asked to find the derivative of $tan(3x)$ using the limit definition

I am bit stuck at the steps, can anyone please explain ?

Thank you so much , would be a great help !

Comment: What definition do you have for the tangent function? Without knowing that, we might give you an answer that's not helpful. My suspicion is that it is in terms of sine and cosine, but in that case, we'll need to know what your definition of those functions is. Showing your steps would likely answer all those questions for us, as well as giving us an idea of your experience lever, so please include your efforts!

Comment: Somewhat similar to:https://socratic.org/questions/58d3b63f11ef6b2266e7470b

Comment: Thank you so much @CameronBuie, I don't know how to type my working , when I type those lot of people down vote me as it is not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's supposed to be directly from the definition, we need to use the formula:
$$ \tan(\alpha+\beta) = \frac{\tan\alpha+\tan \beta}{1-\tan\alpha\cdot\tan\beta}$$
and we need to know that $$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \frac{\tan\epsilon}{\epsilon} = 1 $$
We have:
\begin{align} (\tan 3x)' &= \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{\tan\big(3(x+\epsilon)\big)-\tan (3x)}{\epsilon} = \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{\tan (3x)+\tan(3\epsilon)}{1-\tan (3x)\cdot\tan(3\epsilon)}-\tan (3x)}{\epsilon} = \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{\big(1+\tan^2 (3x)\big)\tan(3\epsilon)}{\epsilon\big(1-\tan (3x)\cdot\tan(3\epsilon)\big)} = \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{3\big(1+\tan^2 (3x)\big)}{1-\tan (3x)\cdot\tan(3\epsilon)} \cdot \frac{\tan(3\epsilon)}{3\epsilon} = \\
&= \frac{3\big(1+\tan^2 (3x)\big)}{1-\tan (3x)\cdot 0} \cdot 1 = \\
&= 3\big(1+\tan^2 (3x)\big) = \frac{3}{\cos^2(3x)}\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much sir

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

$$\tan(3(x+h))-\tan(3x)=(1+\tan(3x+3h)\tan(3x))\tan(3h)$$

and
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\tan(3h)}{h}=3$$

Comment: Thank you so much sir , but how did you get the last limit equals 3 ? @hamam_Abdullah

Comment: @lasanmanujitha L'hospital's rule works, or you can use tan=sin/cos, you should know the limit of sin(3h)/h, and the 1/cos(3h) just goes to 1.

Comment: @lasanmanujitha Using that $\tan(3h)=\frac{\sin(3h)}{\cos(3h)}$.

Comment: Thank you so much